# How to discover google cloud using servicenow discovery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, servicenow

I'm looking to setup Servicenow to discover google cloud platform.
This involves steps to setting up/Configuring on Servicenow and steps to configure on Google cloud as well. I have the steps to configure on servicenow but I do not have the to configure on Google cloud. Can someone please help me with this?

Need the steps to configure on Google cloud. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: There should be an official documentation available for this on both Google Cloud and over service now.

Comment: Was this about what is now the [DiscoveryAPI](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/washingtondc-api-reference/page/app-store/dev_portal/API_reference/DiscoveryAPIScoped/concept/c_DiscoveryAPIScopedAPI.html) provided by ServiceNow?

Answer (score 0):

You can find documentation about this [here](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/store-it-operations-management/page/product/itom/reference/google-gcp-discovery-pattern.html) which includes steps on how to set up on ServiceNow that includes the configuration of the service account (which is technically the Google Cloud Platform's side).

Comment: Unfortunately, that link is now dead.